# Excel VBA - How do I create a cell range from 2 intersecting ranges?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that looks for a ceratin value in Column A and also a different Value in Row 1.

I need to create a new Range value for the cell where the 2 intersect at. Is this possible? If so How do I do it?

This is my code so far:

```
Set DayRng = ws.Range("1:1").Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
Set ActionCell = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:=ActionString, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

If DayRng.Value = Date Then

    ' Set New Due Date
    Worksheets("ActionPlan").Range("E" & (ActionCell.Row)).Value = NewDate

    ' Add Updates to Update field
    Worksheets("ActionPlan").Range(DayRng.Column & "" & ActionCell.Row).Value = Me.txtUpDes.Value

Else
"Do something else"
```

If it is not clear from the code above, I now need to put a new value in the cell with column letter of DayRng and in the Row number of ActionCell.

For example, if DayRng = E1 and ActionCell = A4 then I need a new value to be put in E4

Comment: change `Worksheets("ActionPlan").Range(DayRng.Column & "" & ActionCell.Row)` to `Worksheets("ActionPlan").Cells(ActionCell.Row,DayRng.Column)`

Comment: That worked perfectly. However, I used the Answer from below so have accepted that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if DayRng = E1 and ActionCell = A4 then I need a new value to be put in E4

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ActionPlan").Cells(ActionCell.Row, DayRng.Column).Value = "WhatEver"`

Comment: Oh, you beat me to it! Sorry, my answer below is an exact duplicate of this one.

Comment: Perfect! How did I now spot that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Worksheets("ActionPlan").Cells(ActionCell.Row, DayRng.Column) _
  = "Hello World"
```